# How to Work With XML Elements With The Same Name but At Different Depths of Tree?

Tags: c#, xml

I'd like to get the values of the element "name" child of "age" **only**. Not the values of of any other element "name" (In this case element "name" child of  "person").

As an output I'd like to get "William" and "Sarah".

This XML is a simple example but imagine the tree is deeper and the name of some elements are repeated at certain depths of tree.

Any advice and examples are welcome using a different XML file if it helps to clear confusion.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
  <person>
    <name>Jake</name>
    <age>18</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Steve</name>
    <age>
      <name>William</name>
    </age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Nicole</name>
    <age>
      <name>Sarah</name>
    </age>
  </person>
</root>
```

CODE:

```
public void getE()
{

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("file.xml");

    XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("name");

    for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerXml);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("person").Select(x => new {
                name = x.Element("name"),
                age = x.Element("age"),
                age_name = x.Element("age").Element("name") == null ? string.Empty : (string)x.Element("age").Element("name")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From OP's question: "I'd like to get the values of the element "name" child of "age" only. Not the values of of any other element "name" (In this case element "name" child of "person")."

Comment: Does it really matter?  It is better to give a complete answer so the Op fully understands how to get tags at different levels.